# Error with Xpages ExtLib dialog when using Apache POI to create Excel Book

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

When using XPages ExtLib dialog to create MS Excel using Apache POI, I get an error "An error occurred while updating some of the page. Argument 1 of Node.replaceChild is not an object"  The Export works fine if executed from a button on the XPage.
Domino 9.0.1 FP8
Please explain what I'm doing wrong with the Dialog ?
Thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view
    xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script
            src="/CreateStream.jss"
            clientSide="false">
        </xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:table>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button
                    value="Test Export"
                    id="button1">
                    <xp:eventHandler
                        event="onclick"
                        submit="true"
                        refreshMode="complete">
                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:CreateWorkbookStream();}]]></xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
            </xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:button
                    value="Open Dialog"
                    id="button3">
                <xp:eventHandler
                    event="onclick"
                    submit="false">
                    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.openDialog("#{id:dialog1}");]]></xp:this.script>
                </xp:eventHandler></xp:button></xp:td>
            <xp:td></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xe:dialog id="dialog1">
        <xp:panel>
            <xp:table>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:button
                            value="Test Export"
                            id="button2">
                            <xp:eventHandler
                                event="onclick"
                                submit="true"
                                refreshMode="complete">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:CreateWorkbookStream();}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td></xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
                <xp:tr>
                    <xp:td>
                        <xp:button
                            value="Close Dialog"
                            id="button4">
                            <xp:eventHandler
                                event="onclick"
                                submit="false">
                                <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.closeDialog("#{id:dialog1}");]]></xp:this.script>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
                    </xp:td>
                    <xp:td></xp:td>
                </xp:tr>
            </xp:table>
        </xp:panel>
    </xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

JavaScript Library

```
    function CreateWorkbookStream(){
    importPackage(java.lang);
    importPackage(org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel);
    importPackage(org.apache.poi.hssf.util);

    var sheetName = "sheet1";
    //Create a new workbook object from the poi library
    var wb:HSSFWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    //Create additional sheets using same sytnax and different sheet name
    var sheet1:HSSFSheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName);

    //Create row
    var row:HSSFRow = sheet1.createRow(0);
    var cell:HSSFCell = row.createCell((java.lang.Integer)(0));

    cell.setCellValue("One");

    //Create file name
    var workbookName = "exptest"
    var fileName = workbookName+".xls";

    //Write output
    // The Faces Context global object provides access to the servlet environment via the external content
    var extCont = facesContext.getExternalContext(); 
    // The servlet's response object provides control to the response object
    var pageResponse = extCont.getResponse();
    //Get the output stream to stream binary data
    var pageOutput = pageResponse.getOutputStream();

    // Set the content type and headers
    pageResponse.setContentType("application/x-ms-excel");
    pageResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    pageResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + fileName);
    //Write the output, flush the buffer and close the stream
    wb.write(pageOutput);
    pageOutput.flush();
    pageOutput.close();

    //  Terminate the request processing lifecycle.
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

Comment: suspect that the faces context response has change when the dialog is open.

Comment: My standing advice for those exercises: Create a JavaBean that you add as managed bean that does all the handling and call a method on the class. See for inspiration: https://www.wissel.net/blog/2013/06/managed-beans-xpages-and-testability.html

Comment: Thank you for your advice,  Started my road to using JavaBean.